# Getting a table cell to span multiple columns if the adjacent cells are empty via CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a newb to CSS. I have a page that where an html table is generated at runtime by a bunch of tags. However,data is generated only in one of those cells and the adjacent cells end up being empty.

```
<tr>
<td> Really long data  that is forced to wrap around.</td>
<td> empty cell</td>
<td empty cell </td>
</tr>
```

Is there  a clean(cross browser compatible) way to  get the first cell to span multiple columns via CSS without force a wrap around. Ideally, one would set the `colspan` on the first cell to get it to stretch multiple cells but since the html is generated on the server, this isnt much of an option.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894286/how-to-get-a-td-table-cell-to-span-the-full-width-of-a-table) is the closest set of solution Ive found to my question and it doesnt seem to solve the problem.

Comment: If it's generated on the server, just set it up on the server? You cannot do this via CSS. Check for empty or not and if need be, use a colspan-setting when generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use tables for presentation, rather than tabular content. You should give a look into `display: flexbox` which may help you achieve the effect you want.

Here is a great tutorial https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/